# What would happen in the long term to man-made structures if the Earth was overrun by zombies?

Tags: apocalypse, zombies

If the world was overrun by zombies the logical conclusion would be only waterborne life would be left.  Due to the fact that they don't make sound and are presumably out of range for any of the dead to know they are there (or at least that makes sense to me.) With that in mind if humanity were to fall to zombies wouldn't it be logical to assume that all of our man made structures would wither away and decompose overtime allowing earth to reclaim itself?

Comment: What zombies have to do with the actual withering away of the structures? Are you sure you do not want any *life* on land? And if so, what do you mean by "earth reclaiming itself"?

Comment: It's convention to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer. That way people from every time zone will have a chance to weigh in.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding *Zissouu*! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. It is common to wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer to give everyone in different timezones a chance to have a look at your question and the answers to discuss them and increase the quality. Even if that's not always necessary. And some people might be discouraged from answering if they see you accepted something already. You can accept and unaccept as often as you want. In the end it's your decision. Just a tip for future questions. Have fun!

Comment: You might want to check out the book *The World Without Us* by Alan Weisman. It discusses specifically how things might develop if humans were somehow whisked away from the Earth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most animals wouldn't be negatively affected by a zombie apocalypse.

A critical trait of human hunting ability is our intelligence. If humans are unable to use tools, follow tracks, lay traps, or plan all but the most infirm animals would be able to easily escape. Without the pressure of overfishing, habitat depletion, poaching, and the exotic pet trade many endangered species populations would begin to increase.

The only species that wouldn't do well in such a scenario are those we have domesticated or critically endangered species that have repopulation programs.

Comment: I like how your answer got accepted without answering the question in the slightest xD

Comment: @StegaxKhenacc Check the edit history.

Comment: The other issue would be population where humans have introduced animals, like the cane toad, read about new zealand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduced_species#New_Zealand

Answer (score 1):

If zombies took over the world, and are the standard type (shambling, dumb creatures without superpowers or etc), then they wouldn't do a lot to existing structures. The War against them, however, would. As governments attempt to exterminate the plague, they could nuke every infected city and reduce the world to a radioactive wasteland. Or, they could use conventional bombs to try to rid them from the air.

Wild Animals probably won't die out, unless the zombies use herding methods to kill them.

Answer (score 0):

The zombie virus would probably not be able to wipe out even humanity completely, let alone be compatible with every plant and animal, as well as being able to wipe them all out.

Comment: right I'm assuming that land locked wildlife would be mostly wiped out but marine wildlife would live on. Thus bearing the chance for life to eventually spring anew while the earth healed itself.

Comment: @Zissouu Most land animals would also survive perfectly happily.

Answer (score -1):

Yes; once all non-zombified humans are gone, nature will take it's course and the world will revert to it's natural state (ignoring the mass extinction part) in a few thousand years.